# json.net deserializeobject not handling comma in value

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am deserializing data into object(s) using Json.Net (Newtonsoft).  I am getting the JSON file from another source that I cannot control, and values are coming in with a comma in the value like this:

```
"Hello, World"
```

It has double quotes around it.  When this is deserialized into the object, it splits on the comma and puts Hello into one field value, and World into the next field value.

Is there a serializer setting (JsonSerializerSettings) that will fix this?  I could not find anything obvious.

**Edit: Sorry for the delay - I got caught up in another project then had to do CES... Here is the code I used:**

```
    Dim P As JSONProduct = New JSONProduct
    Dim S As JsonSerializerSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings
    Dim data As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("B:\Downloads\JSON\file.json")

    Try
        P = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, GetType(JSONProduct), S)
    Catch exjr As JsonReaderException
        MsgBox("Reader Exception: " & exjr.Message)
    Catch exjs As JsonSerializationException
        MsgBox("Serialization Exception: " & exjs.Message)
    Catch exj As JsonException
        MsgBox("JSON Exception: " & exj.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: please post an example, I think the problem isn't just the double quotes

Comment: It most likely how you are deserializing or  the type you are deserializing to.  We cant say with no code and no sample

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: @Tink We will also need to see the JSON you are trying to deserialize, and the class(es) (e.g. `JSONProduct`) you are trying to deserialize into.  A full working example demonstrating the problem would be best.

Comment: @BrianRogers - I appreciate the help but can't really post any more.  The class object is nothing more than collections of string properties and arrays of other classes to match the JSON.  I can't provide those because they are huge, and those and the JSON are company proprietary.  I have beyond a doubt traced the problem to there being commas in the quoted string not being handled correctly as the original post showed.

Comment: (cont)   There are a few different ways of using the Newtonsoft library and I was hoping somebody would know of a better way, or a setting for the way I am using it, that might fix this.  Even pre-processing with Regex would be good, but forming the kind of Regex I need would be very difficult with my limited Regex experience.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to JavaScriptSerializer (System.Web.Script.Serialization) and the issue went away.  Too bad, I like the Newtonsoft stuff.